# IntelliJ IDEA 12: How can I run pip install to install libraries in virtual environment?

Tags: intellij-idea, flask, pycharm

I am using `IntelliJ IDEA 12 Ultimate Edition` and creating flask project.

I created the virtualenv using IDEA and using that, but my code has dependency on other libraires I as move forward. For example Flask-Restless.

My code in IntelliJ IDEA looks like

[image]

Is there a way to install Flak-Restless using IntelliJ IDEA 12?

or

do I need to activate my virtualenv on command-line and install it myself?

Is it something IDEA can provide to me?

Answer (score 20):

In IntelliJ IDEA use **Tools** | **Manage Python Packages** dialog to install/uninstall packages for your Python SDK or virtualenv used in project.

Answer (score 6):

Use `pip` `requirements.txt` in your repository root. My `PyCharm` automatically prompt me install absent requirements or if installed versions not equal with `requirements.txt`.

You can install packages from `requirements.txt`:

```
your_python_root_pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can get already installed packages with versions:

```
your_python_root_pip freeze -r requirements.txt
```

For details see pip help. See `requirements.txt` example:

```
flask==0.9
flask-testing==0.4
blinker==1.2
uwsgi==1.4.5
nose
coverage
pep8
```

Comment: but you run pip install from command-line, right? I am more interested if IDEA doesn't find any library and suggest to install it in the IDE using `pip install` rather me leaving IDE and install from command-line

Comment: See PyCharm roadmap: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+2.5+Roadmap. See details about `dependencies management`, `suggest to install or update required libraries`, `distutils / PyPI support` and etc. In PyCharm it supported by default, for IDEA you probaly must install someone plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can install all project packages via `PyCharm 2017.1` by **Tools** / **Python Integrated Tools** / **Package requirements file**. Get there full path to your `requirements.txt` file and PyCharm will ask you to install all dependencies.

Comment: How do I get "Python Integrated Tools" to appear in the Tools menu?